# How to configure Prettier to format Cypress code with chained calls?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I'm using Prettier to format my Cypress code, but it's breaking lines in a way that I don't like. Specifically, it's formatting lines like this:

```
cy.contains("div[role='alert']", "Status alterado com sucesso!").should(
    "be.visible"
);
```

However, I would like it to format the lines like this:

```
cy.contains("div[role='alert']", "Status alterado com sucesso!")
    .should("be.visible");
```

Here are my current settings in `settings.json`:

```
    "prettier.chainedCall": true,
    "prettier.keepFunctionIndentation": true,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "prettier.trailingComma": "es5",
    "prettier.printWidth": 80,
    "prettier.arrowParens": "avoid",
    "prettier.tabWidth": 4,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
```

I've already tried setting the `chainedCall` and `keepFunctionIndentation` options in my VS Code settings, but they don't seem to be working. Is there a way to configure Prettier to format my Cypress code in the way that I want?

Comment: @JV Matos Have you got any formatter for witting cypress test?